# Expressions in Lightning Component - how to round / set scale to a decimal?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Say there is two attributes, 1 and 3.

Dividing them using Lightning expressions will display something like 0.33333333, but I'd prefer to see 0.33.

How do I format them without going into JS controller? Seems like there aren't any [official functions.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm)

Comment: Did the supplied answers not do what you wanted

Answer (score 6):

What about using format in outPutNumber :

```
<ui:outPutNumber aura:id="myNumberFormat" format="#,##0,000.00" value="0.33333333"/>
```

[Reference here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_outputNumber.htm)

Comment: That looks like a best approach. I ended up using JS though: `Math.round((a-b) * 100) / 100`

Answer (score 3):

How about using some Math™ (implementing floor using mod to make a truncation function):

```
floor(n) = n - (n % 1)
```

From floor, if we feed in a number that has been multiplied by 100, apply floor and then divide by 100, we have a rounding (or at least truncation)

```
truncate (n,2) = ((n*100) - ((n*100) % 1))/100
```

Which can be expressed, in lightning as:

```
<ui:outputText value="{!((v.testval*100)-mod((v.testval*100),1))/100}"/>
```

And of course, using your two attributes:

```
<ui:outputText value="{!(((v.testval1/v.testval2)*100)-mod(((v.testval1/v.testval2)*100),1))/100}"/>
```